# Scala Lift - Classpath not found on linux

Tags: scala, lift

I have the following folder:

```
resources/toServe/presentation
```

Where I store uploaded images and files, when displaying an image on my local windows dev machine all works fine and I can do:

```
<img src="/classpath/presentation/test.jpg" />
```

However when I run the app on our production server (RHEL5) I get a 404 with the same path.

In Boot.scala I have:

```
ResourceServer.allow {

    case "presentation" :: tail => true

}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: What directory is `resources` in? What build tool are you using to build the .war file?

Comment: The full path to the resources folder is /src/main/resources/toServe, I'm not yet building the war file, instead I'm using SBT. Thanks

Comment: How are you starting the webapp? Is there any difference in how you start it in development vs. production?

Comment: For windows I use: set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
java -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx712M -Xss2M -jar "%SCRIPT_DIR%\sbt-launcher.jar" %*, for linux I'm using java -Xmx712M -Xss2M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launcher.jar "$@". Both are followed by update ~jetty-run.

Comment: Any chance it's a case sensitivity issue? On Linux, test.jpg != test.JPG.

Comment: The file names are stored in mongodb, so the case is always the same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8451/discussion-between-dave-and-sirjamm)

Answer (score 2):

To fix this for anyone having similar issues, just change "toServe" to "toserve".

Windows treats case differently to Linux.